# How to extract specific text from a corpus?

Tags: r, corpus

I have a corpus with 213 documents which vary in lenght. My aim is to extract from each of the document a specific bit of text which refers to "fiscal policy". The thing that complicates my attempt is that the bit of text I want to extract is not the same from text to text. The only key words that appear regularly at the beginning are *fiscal policy* or *fiscal policies* but nothing more than that.

Let's take an example:

```
df <- data.frame(Text = c("Stackoverflow is a great place where very skilled people can give you advice on coding. It is so good that I hope they are going to sort this problem out. This problem is really killing me. As regards fiscal policy, almost all euro area countries have submitted their updated stability programmes. While these programmes generally indicate that governments plan to proceed towards sound budgetary positions, there are also indications that budget targets do not consistently imply sufficient consolidation and that concrete and credible measures have not yet been specified in all programmes. These indications are a cause of concern and entail risks for the future. MORE TEXT", "Stackoverflow is a great place where very skilled people can give you advice on coding. Regarding regards fiscal policies, almost all euro area countries have submitted their updated stability programmes. MORE TEXT", "Stackoverflow is a great place where very skilled people can give you advice on coding. It is so good that I hope they are going to sort this problem out. As regards fiscal policy, almost all euro area countries have submitted their updated stability programmes. While these programmes generally indicate that governments plan to proceed towards sound budgetary positions, there are also indications that budget targets do not consistently imply sufficient consolidation and that concrete and credible measures have not yet been specified in all programmes. These indications are a cause of concern and entail risks for the future. Against the background of current good times, it is essential that sound budgetary positions are reached in countries with fiscal imbalances and that a pro-cyclical loosening is avoided in all member countries. MORE TEXT", "Stackoverflow is a great place where very skilled people can give you advice on coding. It is so good that I hope they are going to sort this problem out. This problem is really killing me. Turning to fiscal policy, almost all euro area countries have submitted their updated stability programmes. While these programmes generally indicate that governments plan to proceed towards sound budgetary positions, there are also indications that budget targets do not consistently imply sufficient consolidation and that concrete and credible measures have not yet been specified in all programmes. MORE TEXT"))

cp <- corpus (df)
```

The final aim is to get a corpus like this:

```
df <- data.frame(Text = c("As regards fiscal policy, almost all euro area countries have submitted their updated stability programmes. While these programmes generally indicate that governments plan to proceed towards sound budgetary positions, there are also indications that budget targets do not consistently imply sufficient consolidation and that concrete and credible measures have not yet been specified in all programmes. These indications are a cause of concern and entail risks for the future.", "Regarding regards fiscal policies, almost all euro area countries have submitted their updated stability programmes.", "As regards fiscal policy, almost all euro area countries have submitted their updated stability programmes. While these programmes generally indicate that governments plan to proceed towards sound budgetary positions, there are also indications that budget targets do not consistently imply sufficient consolidation and that concrete and credible measures have not yet been specified in all programmes. These indications are a cause of concern and entail risks for the future. Against the background of current good times, it is essential that sound budgetary positions are reached in countries with fiscal imbalances and that a pro-cyclical loosening is avoided in all member countries.", "Turning to fiscal policy, almost all euro area countries have submitted their updated stability programmes. While these programmes generally indicate that governments plan to proceed towards sound budgetary positions, there are also indications that budget targets do not consistently imply sufficient consolidation and that concrete and credible measures have not yet been specified in all programmes."))

cp <- corpus(df)
```

Note that, I would be happy even if I just got to the bit of interest plus "MORE TEXT" that I do not want. I could simply subset it. I do not manage to get there though. So far, I have tried unsuccessfully to use **corpus_segment** as well as unsuccessfully playing with the dataframe.

Can anyone help me with that?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If that is all the information you have, I don't think you can get further than `stringr::str_extract(df$Text, stringr::regex("fiscal.*$", ignore_case=TRUE))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Base R solution not requiring corpus function:

```
trimws(grep("fiscal polic.*", unlist(strsplit(df$Text, "[.]")), ignore.case = TRUE, value = TRUE), "both")
```

In response to the further question -- finding the index and using it subset data:

```
# Return vector of sentences containing pattern: 

trimws(grep("fiscal polic.*", unlist(strsplit(df$Text, "[.]")), ignore.case = TRUE, value = TRUE), "both")

# Store the matched text as a vector: 

matched_text <- trimws(grep("fiscal .*", unlist(strsplit(df$Text, "[.]")), ignore.case = TRUE, value = TRUE), "both")

#Get the index of the dataframe for each element:

matched_text_idx <- sapply(matched_text, function(x){which(grepl(x, df$Text))})

# If you want to subset the dataframe to contain only the elements which contain pattern: 

df$Text[(which(grepl("fiscal polic.*", df$Text)))]
```

Data:

```
    df <- data.frame(Text = c("Stackoverflow is a great place where very skilled people can give you advice on coding. It is so good that I hope they are going to sort this problem out. This problem is really killing me. As regards fiscal policy, almost all euro area countries have submitted their updated stability programmes. While these programmes generally indicate that governments plan to proceed towards sound budgetary positions, there are also indications that budget targets do not consistently imply sufficient consolidation and that concrete and credible measures have not yet been specified in all programmes. These indications are a cause of concern and entail risks for the future. MORE TEXT", "Stackoverflow is a great place where very skilled people can give you advice on coding. Regarding regards fiscal policies, almost all euro area countries have submitted their updated stability programmes. MORE TEXT", "Stackoverflow is a great place where very skilled people can give you advice on coding. It is so good that I hope they are going to sort this problem out. As regards fiscal policy, almost all euro area countries have submitted their updated stability programmes. While these programmes generally indicate that governments plan to proceed towards sound budgetary positions, there are also indications that budget targets do not consistently imply sufficient consolidation and that concrete and credible measures have not yet been specified in all programmes. These indications are a cause of concern and entail risks for the future. Against the background of current good times, it is essential that sound budgetary positions are reached in countries with fiscal imbalances and that a pro-cyclical loosening is avoided in all member countries. MORE TEXT", "Stackoverflow is a great place where very skilled people can give you advice on coding. It is so good that I hope they are going to sort this problem out. This problem is really killing me. Turning to fiscal policy, almost all euro area countries have submitted their updated stability programmes. While these programmes generally indicate that governments plan to proceed towards sound budgetary positions, there are also indications that budget targets do not consistently imply sufficient consolidation and that concrete and credible measures have not yet been specified in all programmes. MORE TEXT"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: @Arma_91 No worries, base R is very useful and often shouldn't be overlooked in favour of packages !

Comment: you are right! I applied your code to my dataframe and it works (better than I expected as it actually graps all the bit where the reference is to "fiscal"). There is only one negative: the structure of the dataframe is lost - no more 213 documents but N bits of characters. It would be spectacular if I could refer these bits to the text they were extracted from. Unlike my example here, there is more than one bit per row.

Comment: @Arma_91 Edited for brevity / optimised for search

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201672/discussion-between-arma-91-and-hello-friend).